# How to use lambdaJ's extract() on method returning generic type without explicit casting

Tags: java, generics, collections, extract, lambdaj

I'm using generics to store reference to arbitrary object.

```
class Option<TypeT>{
    TypeT o;

    Option(TypeT t){
        this.o = o;
    }
    TypeT getReferencedObject(){
        return o;
    }
}
```

I want to use lambdaJ to extract those objects from a collection. Right now i'm using pretty ugly double casting `(List<TypeT>)(List<?>)` and i'm looking for a better/cleaner solution. The problem lies in the `on( sth ).getReferencedObject()` statement, which cannot be parameterized like `on(Option<String>.class).getReferencedObject()`

```
List<Option<String>> options = Arrays.asList(new Option<String>("AAA"), new Option<String>("BBB"));
List<String> string = (List<String>)(List<?>) extract(options, on(Option.class).getReferencedObject());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue stems from a limitation of the language itself - [there are no class literals for concrete parameterized types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390682/697449), which is a result of Java's using [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to implement generics.

An example of a concrete parameterized type would be `Option<String>`. **There is no `Option<String>.class`, only `Option.class`**.

Parameterized types *can* be represented at runtime by [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) instances, which can be acquired using reflection. Some libraries take advantage of this in order to type-safely represent generic types, for example Guava's [`TypeToken<T>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

But unfortunately that doesn't help here. The reason is that LambdaJ's [`on`](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/apidocs/ch/lambdaj/Lambda.html#on%28java.lang.Class%29) method uses a [dynamic proxy](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20dynamic%20proxy) to represent the specified type. This is so that calling something like this:

```
on(Option.class).getReferencedObject()
```

can work its LambdaJ magic behind the scenes. Creating such a proxy ultimately boils down to a call to the Java API's [`Proxy.newProxyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29), or else a custom proxy implementation like [`net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2.2/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.java/). In either case, `Class` instances *specifically* are used to represent the proxied interfaces/classes. So to sum it up, **`on` can't accept anything but a cold hard `Class<T>`**.

What can you do? Your options are limited...

### 1) Stick with what you have:

We know this is ugly and it's definitely bug prone, but it works:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //okay because options is a List<Option<String>>
List<String> strings =
    (List<String>)(List<?>)extract(options, on(Option.class).getReferencedObject());
```

Out of curiosity, I tried this instead:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //not really okay, but let's see what happens
Class<Option<String>> onWhat = (Class<Option<String>>)(Class<?>)Option.class;
List<String> strings = extract(options, on(onWhat).getReferencedObject());
```

But that got me a runtime exception:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `net.sf.cglib.empty.Object$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9d9c54e1` cannot be cast to `java.lang.String`

### 2) Use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
List<String> strings = Lists.transform(
        options,
        new Function<Option<String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Option<String> option) {
                return option.getReferencedObject();
            }
        }
);
```

This is looking rather noisy, but the `Function` can be abstracted away at least:

```
class Option<T> {

    ...

    public static final class Functions {

        //Impl note: Effective Java item 27
        private static final Function<?, ?> GET_REFERENCED_OBJECT =
                new Function<Option<?>, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object apply(Option<?> option) {
                        return option.getReferencedObject();
                    }
                };

        private Functions() { }

        public static <T> Function<Option<T>, T> getReferencedObject() {
            //okay for any T, since Option<T>.getReferencedObject must return a T
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Function<Option<T>, T> withNarrowedTypes =
                    (Function<Option<T>, T>)GET_REFERENCED_OBJECT;
            return withNarrowedTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

Which makes the call site cleaner:

```
List<String> strings = Lists.transform(
        options,
        Option.Functions.<String>getReferencedObject()
);
```

Note that [`Lists.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) returns a transformed *view* of the original `List`. If you want a copy like LambdaJ's `extract` returns, making one is easy enough:

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList(Lists.transform(
        options,
        Option.Functions.<String>getReferencedObject()
));
```

This is all much more verbose but it gives you generic type safety and you get to drop the dynamic proxy sorcery behind the scenes.

### 3) Use the Ol' Plain n' Simple (and wait for Java 8):

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(options.size());
for (Option<String> option : options) {
    strings.add(option.getReferencedObject());
}
```

An often overlooked but pleasantly viable option!