# Does class c implement interface<String>

Tags: java, class, interface, polymorphism, instanceof

I have this interface:

```
interface MyInt<T> {

    public void foo(T t);
}
```

And these classes:

```
class MyString implements MyInt<String> {

    @Override
    public void foo(String t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}

class MyDouble implements MyInt<Double> {

    @Override
    public void foo(Double t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Now I want to test if a class not only implements `MyInt` (i can do that), but if that class implements `MyInt<String>`, my code so far:

```
Class<MyInt> c = MyInt.class;
Class c0 = MyString.class;
Class c1 = MyDouble.class;

System.out.println(c.isAssignableFrom(c0)); //true
System.out.println(c.isAssignableFrom(c1)); //true
```

Every try for adding the String "sublass" (dont even know correct name for T) result in compilation error. Any way to do this?

Comment: You should be able to add a getter to MyInt which returns the class of T. `public Class getImplementedClass() { return T.getClass(); }`

Comment: @BobDalgleish `MyInt` is an interface. You can not add method implementations to an interface. You would need to do it in each implementing class which makes the whole approach useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to test if a class not only implements MyInt, but if that class implements MyInt<String>

You might wanted to do something like

```
Class<MyInt<String> > c = MyInt<String>.class;
```

but this is not possible due to type erasure. See [Java: how do I get a class literal from a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type) for a very good explanation.

To still be able to check whether your class implements an interface which uses some specific type, you can retrieve the generic type arguments of a given class and check the type of it:

```
Class c0 = MyString.class;
Class c1 = MyDouble.class;

ParameterizedType c0Type = (ParameterizedType) c0.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
Class<?> type0Class = (Class<?>) c0Type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

ParameterizedType c1Type = (ParameterizedType) c1.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
Class<?> type1Class = (Class<?>) c1Type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

System.out.println(type0Class.isAssignableFrom(String.class));  // true
System.out.println(type1Class.isAssignableFrom(String.class));  // false
```

This should work for your particular case. You need to adjust the array indexes when you are implementing more than one interface and/or using more than one generic type parameter.

Comment: MyInt<String>.class was the first thing i tried, and thanks, this is exactly what i wanted.