# In Java, how do I implement a method that returns Class<List<String>>

Tags: java, class, generics

One of the generic classes that I'm extending requires that I return a Class object of the correct generic type.  I know how to do this for the normal case, but not when my class contains a generic list.

For example, I know how to implement the first method below, but not the second:

```
public Class<String> getStringKlass() {
    return String.class;
}

public Class<List<String>> getStringListKlass() {
    ???
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how do I get a class literal from a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple as

```
List.class
```

The generic information is there for compile-time. For runtime, generics are ignored and it's only the type of the class that matters.

Comment: That doesn't compile.  It gives me a "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm guessing your method should return `Class<List>` instead of `Class<List<String>>`, but I don't know what problems this might cause, and maybe it should be returning something like `Class<?>`.  But I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: Oops. I didn't mention. You will also need to refactor the signatures of your method to `public Class<List> getKlass()`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that due to type erasure: In Java, if you have a generic type (here: `List<T>`) then at *compile-time* you can use `List<String>`, `List<Date>`, etc. However, at *runtime* all these types are represented by the same `Class` object.

In other words, the following program will output `true`:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(list.getClass() == ArrayList.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've gotten to achieve that is to create a new class that extends some `List<String>`.

```
public class ListOfStrings extends ArrayList<String> { }
```

And then using `<? extends List<String>>` instead of just `List<String>` in your method:

```
public Class<? extends List<String>> getStringListKlass()
{
    return ListOfStrings.class;
}
```

However, I don't know what sort of trouble this might introduce in your code after that.