# How to use Collections.checkedlist

Tags: java, collections

```
List<SomeClass<String>> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass<String>>();
List l = Collections.checkedList(list, SomeClass.class);
```

That is my code.Eclipse tell me there are some errors:

> The method `checkedList(List<E>, Class<E>)` in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments `(List<SomeClass<String>>, Class<SomeClass>)`

how to use checkedList? how to alter the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `Class<SomeClass>` to raw `Class` to make it compile.

```
List<SomeClass<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List l = Collections.checkedList(list, (Class)SomeClass.class);
```

Note that you can't check type parameters at runtime due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 2):

Java cannot check the generic parameter of a type at runtime ([How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)), so `checkedList` will not be able to enforce the `<String>` part of your type signature.

You can add casting to allow this method call, so `checkedList` will enforce that only instances of `SomeClass<?>` are added to the `List`, but you won't have complete type safety at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you can't have class literals of generic type in Java: [Java: how do I get a class literal from a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type) and for `List` containing `<Foo<Bar>>` your class literal would have to be `Foo<Bar>.class`.

Anyway since `checkedList` will add type safety checks at runtime you can try using one of *dirty* solutions like raw types:

```
List<SomeClass<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List l = Collections.checkedList((List)list, SomeClass.class);
```