# Using generic type as class argument

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I  have this class

```
class X<T>{
    public T dowhatever(){
         //jackson parsing
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         T obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, T);
         return obj;
    }
}
```

But apparently, I can't pass `T` to the readValue method. I need a `class` information. Is there a way to generalize it without passing the `Class` object as a paremeter?

p.s:
I have omitted unnecessary code and left what is relevant.

Comment: Basically this is not possible, or at least really really difficult, without the class literal.  C.f. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type

Answer (score 0):

The only way to generalize it is through a sub-class with a specific class as the generic

```
class MyX extends X<Type> {
```

You can obtain the `Type` at runtime as this has to be available for the compiler to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class X<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void dowhatever(T... dummy){
        Class<T> classT = (Class<T>)dummy.getClass().getComponentType();
        System.out.println(classT);
    }
}

class Person { }
```

and

```
X<Person> x = new X<>();
x.dowhatever(/* no arguments */); // -> class Person
```

Or you can get the class object in constructor.

```
class X<T> {

    private final Class<T> classT;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public X(T... dummy) {
        classT = (Class<T>)dummy.getClass().getComponentType();
    }
}
```