# How to get class when have list of models and not just model in Java

Tags: java, android, dualcache

If I have class CalendarModel to get class I use `CalendarModel.class` .
But how when I have list of model? Something like `List < CalendarModel>.class`

This is context in my app in which I need that:
Android easy cache requires that thing
https://github.com/vincentbrison/android-easy-cache

```
  DualCache<AbstractVehicule> cache = new DualCacheBuilder<AbstractVehicule>(CACHE_NAME, TEST_APP_VERSION, AbstractVehicule.class)
                                               .useDefaultSerializerInRam(RAM_MAX_SIZE)
                                               .noDisk();
```

How to write this if I want to cache **list** of AbstractVehicule?

EDIT:
Maybe this is solution: `(Class< List< AbstractVehicule >>)(Class<?>)List.class`

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just specify `List.class`?