# Correct method signature using generics to transform Java collection

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm struggling with determining the correct method signature, using generics, for a method which transforms a `Collection` of type A into a specified collection of type B. For example, I have an `ArrayList` of A, and I want the method to return a `LinkedList` of B. So far, I've come up with

```
<A, B, C extends Collection<B>> C mapCollection(
  final Iterable<A> source,
  final Class<B> destinationClass,
  final Class<C> collectionClass)
```

But, if I write the following code:

```
ArrayList<TypeA> listOfA = getList();
LinkedList<TypeB> listOfB = mapCollection(listOfA, TypeB.class, LinkedList.class);
```

The compiler warns about `mapCollection` returning `LinkedList`. Apparently, it uses the `LinkedList.class` argument to determine the type of `C`, instead of seeing that `C` extends `Collection<B>`?

It gets even more interesting if I do

```
List<TypeB> = mapCollection(listOfA, TypeB.class, LinkedList.class);
```

because then, the compiler gives a type mismatch error, `cannot convert from ArrayList to List<T>`. Interestingly enough, this only happens in Eclipse, `javac` is perfectly happy with this code. Of course, I have to use a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` which I'd rather avoid.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Or is this impossible?

Comment: How is the class the contains this method declared? And where are you calling `mapCollection` from? Are you calling it from within an instance method of the same class?

Comment: `mapCollection` is actually defined in a separate class, containing mapper stuff, which is injected as a bean. So I'm calling it from an instance method of a different class.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? For example `SomeType someVar = ...; someVar.mapCollection(...)`. It makes a difference if the class that contains the `mapCollection` method has generic type parameters a the class level.

Comment: If you want to return other type of collection then you can try simple logic to eg `Collection<r> collect(Collection<t> c){ return r_instance.addAll(c)?r_instance.addAll(c):yourCustomException}` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, you're running into limitations of Java's generics that are caused by erasure. Specifically, a class literal `LinkedList.class` has type `Class<LinkedList>`. It can only represent the *raw type* like `LinkedList`; it cannot represent a parameterized type such as `LinkedList<TypeB>`.

If you had an instance of `Class<LinkedList<TypeB>>` then it could work:

```
Class<LinkedList<TypeB>> clazz = ... ;
List<TypeB> listOfB = mapCollection(listOfA, TypeB.class, clazz);
```

Unfortunately it's clumsy and difficult to get such a class instance. You could cast through raw to get it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<LinkedList<TypeB>> clazz = (Class<LinkedList<TypeB>>) (Class) LinkedList.class;
```

but this is hardly better than what you have now.

You might investigate techniques such as Guava's [`TypeToken`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) class (still in beta as of Guava 20). For background see the original article ["Super Type Tokens"](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) from Neal Gafter and an update on its [limitations](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html).

---

The main problem with using a type token is that it relies on the ability of the callee (`mapCollection` in this case) to be able to create an instance of the destination class. By convention, Java's collections have a no-arg constructor, so this is simple enough to be called reflectively. But what if some customization is necessary, such as specifying an initial capacity, or a comparator for sorting? Dealing with these is very difficult when using type tokens.

The Java 8 approach is instead to pass a function -- a `Supplier` -- that creates the destination instance. This lets the caller specify the type, and also any specialized constructor arguments, while it lets the callee determine when creation occurs. To do this, you'd rewrite your method signature like so:

```
<A, B, C extends Collection<B>> C mapCollection(
    final Iterable<A> source,
    final Supplier<C> supplier) { ... }
```

and you'd call it with a lambda expression:

```
List<TypeB> listOfB = mapCollection(listOfA, () -> new LinkedList<TypeB>());
```

or with a method reference:

```
List<TypeB> listOfB = mapCollection(listOfA, LinkedList::new);
```

Note that the type parameters of `LinkedList` are correctly inferred in the method reference case.

As a bonus, the `mapCollection` implementation needn't deal with any reflection. All it needs to do is call `supplier.get()`.

P.S. Don't use `LinkedList`.

Comment: Ah, the Java 8 solution looks very elegant! Two more follow-up questions though! First: shouldn't it be `LinkedList<TypeB>::new` or something like that? And second: what's wrong with `LinkedList`? I generally use `LinkedList` when I don't need random access but only iteration.

Comment: Somehow, `LinkedList::new` just works. Apparently, the compiler is smart enough to understand what I mean. Excellent solution, finally allows me to get rid of all the `@SuppressWarnings`!

Comment: And to answer my other follow-up question as well, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/323889/3676968 is a good summary of why not to use `LinkedList` except in specialized circumstances. I used `LinkedList` because I was wary of the re-allocation of `ArrayList`, but actually it might be less of a problem than I thought. Especially as I now can initialize the new list with the correct capacity using the lambda expression!

Comment: @Michel Yes, the type inference works well for the method reference, so it's not necessary to specify the type parameter explicitly as in `LinkedList<TypeB>::new`. It also works for the lambda expression, where you can use the diamond operator: `() -> new LinkedList<>()`.

Comment: @Michel Sorry about the editorial comment about LinkedList. :-) It's a bit of a pet peeve for me. The answer you found is a good one. There are cases where it's preferable to use a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList or ArrayDeque, but they're very rare.

Comment: ah I didn't even try <>, and I've just committed everything! Oh well... And, don't apologize for the `LinkedList`, I've learned something so it was useful :) never really thought about the memory overhead being so big.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: considering how often we see questions here, using `LinkedList` for no good reason, that remark is justified. Apparently, the message needs to be spread more.

Comment: @Holger OK, thanks, I shall carry on with the crusade. :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Type erasure* is getting in your way. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type). You can't retain `C` bounded type parameters (`extends Collection<B>`) while defining it as a `Class` type parameter.

You can provide a `C` type directly:

```java
<A, B, C extends Collection<B>> void mapCollection(
    final Iterable<A> source,
    final Class<B> destinationClass,
    final C collectionClassInstance);
```

This way `C` will comply with `extends Collection<B>`, but the method signature won't be so elegant.

You can also use the Reflection API to obtain the type parameter. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680/2657100).

Answer (score -1):

The compiler warns you because the method returns `LinkedList.class` but you are expecting an instance of `List<TypeB>`. You cannot do this with generics in Java without compiler warnings. And you cannot do `List<TypeB>.class`, it just doesn't work. **It is impossible.**

However, following code is a valid case:

```
<A, B, C> Collection<B> mapCollection(
  final Iterable<A> source,
  final Class<B> destinationClass,
  final Class<C> collectionClass){...}
Collection<TypeB> = mapCollection(listOfA, TypeB.class, LinkedList.class);
```

And this is as far as you can get with generics.