# How to call this generic method?

Tags: java, generics

How to call the 'test' method below?

```
static <T> T test(Class<Template<T>> type) {
  // ...
}

static class Template<T> {
  T data;
}
```

Can't call like this:

```
test(Template<String>.class);
```

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "Can't call like this"? What happened when you tried?

Comment: What your test method returns? This code can not compile.

Comment: Check the answer of cletus and Santi P. in [Java: how do I get a class literal from a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type).