# Java: Class Type mismatch

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have classes that are structured like the ones below:

```
interface Z {}

interface Y extends Z {}

interface X extends Y {}


private static class A<T extends Z> {}

private static class B<T extends Y> extends A<T> {}

private static class C extends B<X> {}
```

Why is the first one valid while the second one is not?

```
private Class<? extends A<? extends Z>> clazz = C.class; // valid
private Class<? extends A<? extends Z>> clazzb = B.class; // error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<TEST.B> to Class<? extends TEST.A<? extends TEST.Z>>
```

I guess it is because the type of `Y` is unclear in the second example but how would you be able to clarify it?

Thank you

Comment: May be because `B` is generics where `T` is undefined and in `C` type of B is defined as `X` since you extend `B<X>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: how do I get a class literal from a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type)

Comment: @Eklavya Yes I guess so. While `T` in `B` is not defined it has to be at least `Y` and therefore should qualify as `Z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Java Class literal constraint

Simply said; no you can't bound the [`Class` literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) assignment as `B<T>` is a generic type, i.e. you can have:

```
Class<? extends A<? extends Z>> clazzb = B<X>.class; // illegal statement
// OR
Class<? extends A<? extends Z>> clazzb = B<W>.class; // assuming W is a sub-type of X
```

as there is only one class literal (in terms of byte code (runtime) and in terms of language constraints (compile-time)): **`B.class`**

And since the *compiler* won't be able to know of which type the type parameter `T` would be for the `B` class, it won't allow such an assignment.

### Legal assignment

Below assignment statement would be legal (compiles fine):

```
Class<? extends A> clazzb = B.class;
```

but with warnings and that would perfectly complies with the *[Generic Class and Type Parameters Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)*.

I've seen many times a *Java* specific-pattern where developers work-around the compiler type-check with a generic utility method *inferring* its return type to match the assigned reference type:

```
<!-- language : lang-java -->

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Class<T> inferType(Class<?> clazz) {
    return (Class<T>) clazz;
}
```

Then you would be able to perform *what used to be forbidden*:

```
Class<? extends A<? extends Z>> clazzb = generify(B.class);
```

Note that this should be nothing but a **non-recommended** workaround. Just to let you be more sure, here down a ***quite confusing*** statement that compiles just fine:

```
Class<C> clazzb = generify(A.class);
```

At first glance, that should not work, but it will as you are assigning a *class literal* to a *class reference* after all.