# How to get the class of a generic interface with wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to achieve to get a class from his name.
In my case all classes I want to get implements the generic interface `Prototype<T>`.

But the delicate part of my problem is that I'm "Warningophobe".

I wrote:

```
// Warning: Usage of interface raw type
Class<? extends Prototype> prototypeClass;
try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("mova.game.monster.Goblin");
    prototypeClass = clazz.asSubclass(Prototype.class);
    System.out.println(prototypeClass);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code work, but here, my IDE (IntellIJ) tell me that I'm using my "raw interface".

I know I can do that:

```
Class<? extends Prototype<?>> prototypeClass;
try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("mova.game.monster.Goblin");
    // Warning: unchecked cast
    prototypeClass = (Class<? extends Prototype<?>>) clazz.asSubclass(Prototype.class);
    System.out.println(prototypeClass);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

But now, I have an uncheked cast.

So, is there a proper way to achieve this problem without warning?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type Just suppress the unchecked cast warning.

Comment: I've allready tried but it leads to a compilation error:
Required Type: Class<? extends Prototype<?>>
Provided Type: Class<capture of ? extends Prototype>

Comment: Do you need to obtain the class from a String name?  If there are a limited number of classes implementing Prototype, you can use a different representation, like an enum, and map each constant to a factory method.  If you might be dealing with third party code that declares its own Prototype implementations, you may want to use [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Comment: I have to instantiate hundred of objects from json models in a file. These models could contain a class name. So I have to retreive the class. These parts work. The only problems are the warning when I want to subclass as Prototype.