# A special case of Java generics matching

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to resolve a dubious point that has been affecting some parts of my code for years — it is fixed with a trivial cast, but now I'd like to understand the rationale behind it and possibly a reference in official specifications.

Let me introduce this piece of code:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

class BaseClass<T, R> {
  R getSomething() { return null; }
  static <U> U method1 (final U arg1) { return arg1; }
  static <U> U method2 (final U arg1, final Class<? extends U> arg2) { return arg1; }
  static <U> U method3 (final U arg1, final Supplier<? extends U> arg2) { return arg1; }
}
```

Now let me have a subclass with a partial generics binding (`T` is still unbound):

```
class DerivedClass<T> extends BaseClass<T, String> {
  private String s;

  void test (final DerivedClass<T> arg) {
    final var m1 = method1(arg);
    s = m1.getSomething();

    final DerivedClass<T> m3 = method1(arg);
    s = m3.getSomething();

    final var m2 = method2(arg, DerivedClass.class);
    // 1. ERROR: requires String, found Object
    s = m2.getSomething();

    // 2. WARNING: unchecked assignment DerivedClass to DerivedClass<T>
    final DerivedClass<T> m4 = method2(arg, DerivedClass.class);
    s = m4.getSomething();

    final var m5 = method3(arg, () -> new DerivedClass<>());
    s = m5.getSomething();
    } 
}
```

With `method1` everything is fine and the returned object carries the binding `R` -> `String`. In other words, the `U` type of `arg1` is correctly propagated to the result.

With `method2` the binding is lost (and "downgraded" to `Object`): this ends up in a warning if I force things with an explicit type declaration of `m4` (of course an explicit cast would work too) and an error if I use `var`.

With `method3`, in spite of `arg2` being declared in a similar way as in `method2`, everything is fine again.

So it seems that the culprit is the presence of an argument of `Class<>` type. Why? In general, why doesn't the compiler use `arg1` for a complete match even when there is a `Class<>` parameter?

As far as I can remember this happens since Java 5 (of course the portions with `var` refer to Java 17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case of `method3` is not similar to the case of `method2` at all. Namely, there are no [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5133585) involved when calling `method3`. `DerivedClass` in `DerivedClass.class` is a raw type.

It *would* be similar if you return a raw `DerivedClass` in the supplier:

```
final var m5 = method3(arg, () -> new DerivedClass());

// this doesn't compile, for the same reason as in the method2 case
s = m5.getSomething();
```

The type argument for `method2` *cannot* be inferred as `DerivedClass<T>`, because then the second parameter (`arg2`) would be of type `Class<? extends DerivedClass<T>>`, but you are passing a `Class<DerivedClass>` to it.

It's like assigning a `Class<DerivedClass>` to `Class<? extends DerivedClass<T>>` variable:

```
// this does not compile either
Class<? extends DerivedClass<T>> x = DerivedClass.class;
```

This doesn't compile because the raw `DerivedClass` is not a subtype of `DerivedClass<T>`. In fact, if you look at [section 4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) of the JLS, `DerivedClass` is a direct *supertype* of `DerivedClass<T>`.

> Given a generic class or interface `C` with type parameters F1,...,Fn (n > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where each of Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - The raw type `C`.

Therefore, the type parameter of `method2` is inferred as the raw `DerivedClass`. This works for `arg1` too, as the generic `DerivedClass<T>` is a subtype of the raw `DerivedClass`.

That said, [it is not possible to get a `Class<DerivedClass<T>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2390662/5133585) unless you do unchecked casts.

Now you might be wondering how this assignment works if `method2` returns a raw `DerivedClass`, but you are assigning it to `DerivedClass<T>`:

```
final DerivedClass<T> m4 = BaseClass.method2(arg, DerivedClass.class);
```

This works because in assignment contexts just are [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) to work like this. The important sentence is:

> If, after the conversions listed above have been applied, the resulting type is a raw type (§4.8), an unchecked conversion (§5.1.9) may then be applied.

There is an implicit unchecked conversion here converting `DerivedClass` to `DerivedClass<T>`. This is also why you get the warning.

Comment: That statement in section 4.10.2 is precisely what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because both `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` are generic classes, but `DerivedClass.class` is a raw type (namely `Class<DerivedClass>` and not `Class<DerivedClass<T>>`).

`var` is inferred to be the raw type and your statement is identical to:

```
final DerivedClass m2 = method2(arg, DerivedClass.class);
```

Once you use raw types, all generic information is "lost"/erased and you have to deal with plain `Object`s.

`this.<DerivedClass<T>>method2(arg, DerivedClass.class)` should make `m2` generic again (but you probably still have the unchecked cast warning, just for the argument).

And it's exactly this "unchecked assignment" that's causing the issues (unchecked from the raw type to the generic closed type).