Casting Class<? extends Enum<?>> to Class<T extends Enum<T>>
I have some code maintaining a map of proto enums to their fully qualified descriptor names like so:
class EnumRegistry {

    Map<String, Class<? extends Enum<?>>> ENUM_DESCRIPTOR_MAP = ImmutableMap.of(
        Status.getDescriptor().getFullName(), 
        Status.class,
        // ... other enums
        );

    public static Class<? extends Enum<?>> getEnumClass(String enumTypeName) {
        return checkNotNull(ENUM_DESCRIPTOR_MAP.get(enumTypeName), "Unsupported enum type");
    }
}

I have another bit of code that needs to pass the enum class to a method with this signature:
class OtherClass {
    // Gets some stored enum value
    public <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnum(Class<T> clazz) {
        //... some work
    }
}

The idea form of this code would look like:
String enumDescriptor = "some.package.Status"
OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
other.getEnum(EnumRegistry.getEnumClass(enumDescriptor));

This is not happy code with an error something like:
method getEnum in class package.Other cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<T>
  found:    java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Enum<?>>
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.Enum<?>
    upper bounds: java.lang.Enum<T>javac(compiler.err.cant.apply.symbol)

I have a workaround using a helper method that solves the compiler by introducing a helper method:
public void doWork() {
    String enumDescriptor = "some.package.Status";
    OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
    getEnumValue(enumDescriptor, other);
}

// Required helper method to make compiler happy
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumValue(String enumDescriptor, OtherClass other) {
    Class<T> enumClass = (Class<T>) EnumRegistry.getEnumClass(enumDescriptor);
    return other.getEnum(enumClass);
}

My question is, why does the work-around quiet the error? Is there a more intuitive way to communicate to the compiler the enum class's type when making the call to OtherClass.getEnum(...)?
Edit:
I revised my code a little bit to do the cast in EnumRegistery:
class EnumRegistry {
    
    // ...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Class<T extends Enum<T>> getEnumClass(String enumTypeName) {
        Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClazz =  checkNotNull(ENUM_DESCRIPTOR_MAP.get(enumTypeName), "Unsupported enum type");
        return (Class<T>) enumClass;
    }
}

Doing so lets me at least avoid the cast outside of this file, but I still am forced to use a templated helper method:
public void doWork() {
    String enumDescriptor = "some.package.Status";
    OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
    getEnumValue(enumDescriptor, other);
}

// required helper method to make compiler happy
private <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumValue(String enumDescriptor, OtherClass other) {
    Class<T> enumClass = EnumRegistry.getEnumClass(enumDescriptor);
    return other.getEnum(enumClass);
}

And by that I mean the compiler will not let me directly pass the value in:
String enumDescriptor = "some.package.Status"
OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
other.getEnum(EnumRegistry.getEnumClass(enumDescriptor)); // Does not compile

Giving me the rather nasty type error:
method getEnum in class OtherClass cannot be applied to given types;
            other.getEnum(
                 ^
  required: Class<T#1>
  found:    Class<T#2>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: T#3
    upper bound(s): Enum<T#3>,Enum<T#5>
  where T#1,T#2,T#3,T#4,T#5 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Enum<T#1> declared in method <T#1>getEnum(Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Enum<T#2>
    T#3 extends Enum<T#4>
    T#4 extends Enum<T#3>
    T#5 extends Enum<T#5> declared in method <T#5>getEnumClass(String)


Simply because you've casted the result of GetEnumClass to (Class), which is not an implicit casting.

There is no way to make a Map return values with different generic types, unless you know the type before retrieving the value.  What you can do is use a key which is a typed object instead of a String, somewhat like the constants of StandardSocketOptions.  Each constant would contain the value type’s Class object, enabling you to safely cast the corresponding value.

I'm not sure I fully understand your approach @VGR
My understanding is that because all enums extend the super class Enum<T extends Enum<T>> (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-in-a/0596007736/re131.html) you cannot store a collection of enums and keep the parameterized type (which is actually itself). You end up with
Collection<? extends Enum<?>>
Because of type erasure the parameter type is lost (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type).
But the casting ~should~ be safe since enums are ALWAYS T extends ENUM<T>

Essentially, ? extends Enum<?> will never match T extends Enum<T> because, without the T, there is no way to assure the compiler that both questions marks represent the same type.  Does EnumRegistry allow outside code to add to the registry?  Or is there a known, finite set of enum classes?

The Registry class is finite and manually appended to with new classes.
In my specific usecase I'm reading an enum value from a database and need to instantiate it into it's original enum class. The database stores the int ordinal and the string descriptor. Using these I can fetch the class and instantiate it, assuming I can map descriptors to enum class objects. The mapping should change rarely as it contains all enum values we store in our schema.
FWIW my code, though I feel is hacky, does work in my testing.

There is no way to do this.  No matter what, you can never safely cast something to <E extends Enum<E>>.
However, something that might or might not suit your needs is creating a marker interface. For example:
public sealed interface EnumType
permits Color,
        Size,
        Shape {

    String name();
    int ordinal();
}

public enum Color
implements EnumType {
    RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, INDIGO, VIOLET
}

public enum Size
implements EnumType {
    SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE
}

public enum Shape
implements EnumType {
    CIRCLE, SQUARE, TRIANGLE
}

And then:
import java.util.Map;

public class EnumRegistry {
    private final Map<String, Class<? extends EnumType>> typesByName =
        Map.of(
            Color.class.getName(), Color.class,
            Size.class.getName(), Size.class,
            Shape.class.getName(), Shape.class);

    public Class<? extends EnumType> getEnumType(String name) {
        Class<? extends EnumType> cls = typesByName.get(name);
        if (cls == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid name: \"" + name + "\"");
        }
        return cls;
    }
}

The disadvantage is that you still cannot use EnumSet or EnumMap.   Any attempt to do so would be met with the same problem:  There is no way to get a type matching <E extends Enum<E>> without an unsafe cast.
However, you can at least get a list of constants reflectively, using Class.getEnumConstants.  I don’t know if this is enough to serve your purposes.
